# Leaflet Markerclusterer with Leaflet.Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, openstreetmap, leaflet

**Question:** Is it possible to use [Leaflet.label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label) on [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)?

**Problem:** I am trying to have a HTML div appear when the cursor hovers over a cluster icon.

For a normal Marker, you can use attach a label to a marker using

```
L.marker([-37.7772, 175.2606]).bindLabel('Look revealing label!').addTo(map);
```

Comment: Have you tried? You can provide an `iconCreateFunction`

Comment: Mhm... or listen for `clustermouseover`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WUXXz/

```
var label = null;

markers.on('clustermouseover', function (a) {
    label = new L.Label().setLatLng(a.layer.getLatLng())
        .setContent('<p>Hello world!<br />This is a nice popup.</p>')
        .openOn(map);
});

markers.on('clustermouseout', function () {
   if (label) {
      label.close();
      label = null;
   }
});
```